# ADL not working outside (even of structure)

Tags: c++, scope, overloading, overload-resolution, argument-dependent-lookup

If I have a structure the overloads `begin`, `end`, etc. like the following:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T>
struct Array10
{
private:
    std::array<T, 10> m_array;
public:
    constexpr auto begin()
    {
        return std::begin(m_array); // #1
    }

    constexpr auto end()
    {
        return std::end(m_array);
    }

    // cbegin, cend, rbegin, rend, crbegin, crend
};

int main()
{
    Array10<int> arr;
    std::fill(
    std::begin(arr), // #2
    std::end(arr),
    0);
}
```

then I understand why I have to use `std::begin` instead of `begin` in #1(because that's the closest scope `begin` is defined in), but I don't understand why i have to use it in #2.
My first guess would be because `Array10` is in the same namespace as `main`, but putting it into its own namespace didn't solve the problem.

So: Why does ADL not find `std::begin` in `main`(#2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADL doesn't find members.  It finds free functions.

You have a member `foo.begin()`, not a free function `begin(foo)`.

```
friend constexpr auto begin(Array10&)
{
    return std::begin(m_array); // #1
}
friend constexpr auto begin(Array10 const&)
{
    return std::begin(m_array); // #1
}
```

those are non-member `begin` functions that will be found via ADL.

Comment: Actually, just putting `using std::begin;` etc. in Array10's namespace also works and is simpler.